# UserVoice for Windows Phone developers

Tags: api, windows-phone-7

If a user wants to request a feature, he can ask it on Windows Phone's UserVoice page.

Where should a developer go to post an API feature request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The team maintains a site for this at http://wpdev.uservoice.com.